# Any suggestions to improve my recursive function?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I have a list of categories objects like the list below. The problem with this list is that I have categories and brands mixed, and I only need to get the brands from this list.

I know which ones are the brands, because if I navigate in the parentCategoryIds, I will get the root parent (which is id: brands, parentCategoryId: None)

```
categories = [
      #brands
      { "id": "brands", "parentCategoryId": None },
      { "id": "ls", "parentCategoryId": "brands" },
      { "id": "bleed", "parentCategoryId": "brands" },
      { "id": "shape", "parentCategoryId": "brands" },
      { "id": "graze", "parentCategoryId": "brands" },
      { "id": "item", "parentCategoryId": "brands" },
      { "id": "install", "parentCategoryId": "brands" },
      { "id": "horror", "parentCategoryId": "brands" },
      { "id": "thanks", "parentCategoryId": "brands" },
      { "id": "scrape", "parentCategoryId": "brands" },
      { "id": "shelter", "parentCategoryId": "brands" },
      { "id": "dynamic", "parentCategoryId": "brands" },
      { "id": "under", "parentCategoryId": "shape" },
      { "id": "right", "parentCategoryId": "shape" },
      { "id": "base", "parentCategoryId": "shape" },
      { "id": "scrap", "parentCategoryId": "shape" },
    
      # categories
      { "id": "root", "parentCategoryId": None },
      { "id": "bark", "parentCategoryId": "rich" },
      { "id": "rich", "parentCategoryId": "sting" },
      { "id": "rich", "parentCategoryId": "sting" },
      { "id": "sting", "parentCategoryId": "root" },
    ]
```

To solve this issue, I wrote the function below. But I think it will be very slow, since this list is only an example, the original list has hundred of records.
In this function, I'm navigating through the parents until I find the root (if the root == brand, I know I have a brand, so I can add to a separated list; if not, I just ignore).
I'd would like to know if I can do it better, so if I pass a bigger list, it would not be a problem.

```
brands = []

def getParent(id):
  for obj in categories:
    if obj['id'] == id:
      return obj

def is_brand(obj):
  if obj['id'] == 'brands' and obj['parentCategoryId'] == None:
    return True
  
  if obj['id'] == 'root':
    return False
  
  if not obj['parentCategoryId'] == None:
    return is_brand(getParent(obj['parentCategoryId']))


for obj in categories:
  if is_brand(obj):
    brands.append(obj)

print(brands)
```

Comment: If you have working code that you want reviewed for enhancement or optimization, your question should be asked at [codereview.se] instead - it was created specifically for that purpose. Please make sure you read their guidelines before posting there. (Also, when asking a code-related question, the first tag you add should be for the language you're using.)

Comment: Note that your `is_brand(obj)` returns `None` when hitting `obj['parentCategoryId'] is None` without `obj['id'] == 'brands' or obj['id'] == 'root'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has a better time complexity O(n * m) where m is the maximum depth of this graph, yours is O(n^2*m) if I calculated correctly.

```py
def get_brands():
    brands = []
    lookup_categories = dict([(category['id'], category['parentCategoryId']) for category in categories])
    for id, parent in lookup_categories.items():
        if id == 'brands':
            brands.append(id)
            continue
        
        while parent is not None and parent != 'brands':
            parent = lookup_categories[parent]
        
        if parent:
            brands.append(id)
    return brands
```

Another approach I was thinking about is using a disjoint set but I couldn't find a builtin library that has that data structure in python.

Comment: (This appends strings to `brands` instead of dicts.)

Answer (score 2):

Improving `is_brand()`'s resource consumption looks solving an [XY-problem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) 
The way you present it, it *may* be avoided as simple as

```
brands = [
        { "id": "brands", "parentCategoryId": None },
        { "id": "ls",     "parentCategoryId": "brands" },
        …
        { "id": "scrap",  "parentCategoryId": "shape" },
    ]
non_brands = [
      # categories
        { "id": "root", "parentCategoryId": None },
        { "id": "bark", "parentCategoryId": "rich" },
        …
    ]
categories = brands + non_brands
```

---

There are *brands* and *categories*, described by attributes *id* and *parentCategoryId*.
Modelling *brands* as (Python) objects:
If there are responsibilities for *brands* and *categories* alike, there should be a common base class:

```
class node:
    """ Each node has a unique non-None id and a parent. """
    def __init__(self, node_id, parent=None):
        if node_id is None:
            raise hell       # handling "unique" left as an exercise
        self.id = node_id    # note the syntax decoration
        self.parent = parent

    def is_brand(self):
        return False         # isinstance(self, brand)


class brand(node):
    """ A brand is a node with root category "brands". """
    def is_brand(self):
        return True


class category(node):
    """ A category is a node with root category "root". """
    pass
```